# SQL Server : incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID Error with SQL Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used CTE and getting compilation error for last CTE. long time search google but still not understand where I made the mistake in code. so please some one tell me what to change in code to fix the error message

> Incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID

This CTE is throwing the error and this is last CTE in my code.

```
,Cte2 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             EarningID, Section, LineItem, DisplayInCSM, Type, 
             Broker, ItemValue, Period, hierarchy
         FROM
             Cte1) t
    PIVOT
        (MAX(ItemValue)
             FOR Broker IN ([5W],[8K],[CL],[DA],[EQ],[FA],[GS],[HM],[HQ],[JY],[KW],[ML],[MS],[MV],[SL],[UA],[WB])
        ) AS P
)
```

My full code

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Ticker VARCHAR(20), 
@TickerID VARCHAR(20),
@ClientCode VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE @CSM_ID INT
SET @TickerID='ADS'
SET @ClientCode='ADS'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Brokers') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Brokers
END

SELECT DISTINCT @Ticker=Ticker FROM tblTickerMasterId WHERE MasterId=@TickerID
SELECT TOP 1 @CSM_ID=CSM_ID FROM tblCSM_Tuner_Client WHERE TickerID=@TickerID

SELECT * Into #Brokers FROM
(
    Select A.BrokerCode, B.BrokerName                                                  
    From tblClientBroker_Earnings A                                                  
    Join tblBroker B ON SUBSTRING(A.BrokerCode,1,len(A.BrokerCode)-charindex('-',A.BrokerCode))=B.Brokercode                                                       
    Where A.ClientCode=@ClientCode And A.Ticker=@Ticker                                          
    /*AND A.BrokerCode IN (SELECT [DATA] FROM SplitStringToTable(@SelectedBrokers,',') WHERE TRIM([DATA])<>'')*/
) x

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(BrokerCode)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT BrokerCode
    FROM #Brokers where TRIM(BrokerCode) <> ''
) AS B
ORDER BY B.BrokerCode

;WITH DirectReports as 
(
    SELECT      CSM_ID, 
                ID, 
                ParentID, 
                DisplayInCSM, 
                Type,
                FontName,
                FontStyle,
                FontSize,
                UnderLine,
                BGColor,
                LineItemID,
                Presentation,
                BrokerOrientation,
                AnnualFormat,
                CalculationMethod,
                Indent,
                FGColor,
                Box,
                HeadingSubHeading,
                ColOrder,
                @TickerID AS TickerID,
                hierarchy = FORMAT(ID,'0000'), 
                level = 0

    FROM        tblCSM_ModelDetails 
    WHERE       ISNULL(ParentID, 0) = 0
                AND Type<>'BM'
                AND CSM_ID=@CSM_ID

    UNION ALL
    SELECT      e.CSM_ID, 
                e.ID, 
                e.ParentID, 
                e.DisplayInCSM, 
                e.Type,
                e.FontName,
                e.FontStyle,
                e.FontSize,
                e.UnderLine,
                e.BGColor,
                e.LineItemID,
                e.Presentation,
                e.BrokerOrientation,
                e.AnnualFormat,
                e.CalculationMethod,
                e.Indent,
                e.FGColor,
                e.Box,
                e.HeadingSubHeading,
                e.ColOrder,
                @TickerID AS TickerID,
                hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + FORMAT(e.id,'0000'), 
                level = level + 1

    FROM        tblCSM_ModelDetails e
    JOIN        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
    WHERE       e.Type<>'BM'
                AND e.CSM_ID=@CSM_ID
)

,Cte1 as 
(
    SELECT AA.EarningID,AA.Section,AA.LineItem,AA.Ticker, r.DisplayInCSM, r.Type,r.hierarchy, AA.Broker, AA.ItemValue, AA.Period,r.ColOrder
    FROM DirectReports r 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (                                                  
        Select b.*,L.ID AS LineItemID,L.TickerID                                                     
        From tblOutputDetl_CSMTuner b                                                  
        INNER JOIN TblLineItemTemplate L 
        ON b.LineItem= L.LineItem 
        WHERE b.Ticker=@Ticker AND L.TickerID=@TickerID                                    
    ) AA
    ON (AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID 

)
,Cte2 as 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
    (
        SELECT EarningID,Section,LineItem, DisplayInCSM, Type, Broker, ItemValue, Period,hierarchy
        from Cte1
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(ItemValue)
        FOR Broker IN ([5W],[8K],[CL],[DA],[EQ],[FA],[GS],[HM],[HQ],[JY],[KW],[ML],[MS],[MV],[SL],[UA],[WB])
    ) AS P
)

SELECT * FROM Cte2 Order BY hierarchy

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Brokers') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Brokers
END
```

Comment: `ON (AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID ` should be `ON AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID`.

Comment: Personal pet peeve: it's not `;WITH` it's just `WITH`. `;` is a statement terminator; it goes at the end of **every** statement in the batch. It's not a "beginningator" nor does it just go at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.  Terminate all of your statements properly. Not doing so is deprecated anyway, so start building good practices now.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis here

```
ON (AA.LineItemID=r.LineItemID
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. long time i stuck to this issue.